# Where should I put the while loop/boolean?

Tags: java, while-loop, boolean

I made a method should pull up a menu with a list of actions, allows users to choose an action, execute the action, then goes back to the menu and repeats until the user chooses to end the session. I'm currently at a bit lost on what to do with the while loop and the boolean endSession(), which I've been shuffling around in the code that sometimes lets me compile it and never does what I want it to do. The place I currently have it causes it to not only skip the action, but loop infinitely. ***I don't really need to know what's exactly wrong, I just want to know where to put the while loop/boolean endSession (and although not necessary, an explaination for why the answer works would be nice).***

```
//package bookStoreLab;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BookStoreDriver {
private static final int PRINT_INVENTORY=1;
private static final int SEARCH_TITLE=2;
private static final int SEARCH_AUTHOR=3;
private static final int AVAILABLE_BOOKS=4;
private static final int NEW_RELEASES=5;
private static final int PURCHASE=6;
private static final int ADD_INVENTORY=7;
//include rest of constants here for all choices
private static Scanner keyboard;

public static void main(String[] arg) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException{
    System.out.println("\f");
    keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    BookStore booky = new BookStore();
    System.out.println("*****" + 
    "Welcome To Your Local Book Store!" + "*****");
    booky.inputBooks();
    boolean endSession = false;
    int choice = getChoice(endSession);
    if(choice==0){
        endSession = true;
    }
    if(choice==PRINT_INVENTORY){
        booky.printInventory();
    }
    if(choice==SEARCH_TITLE){
        booky.searchByTitle();
    }
    if(choice==SEARCH_AUTHOR){
        booky.searchByAuthor();
    }
    if(choice==AVAILABLE_BOOKS){
        booky.printAvailableBooks();
    }
    if(choice==NEW_RELEASES){
        booky.printNewReleases();
    }
    if(choice==PURCHASE){
        booky.purchase();
    }
    if(choice==ADD_INVENTORY){
        booky.addToInventory();
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Please choose an option that's actually listed.");
    }
    printFarewell();
}
public static int getChoice(boolean a){
    int choice=-1;
    while(!a){    
        System.out.println("\n\nWhat store service would you like" +
        "to perform? (Enter 0-7)");
        System.out.println("\t0. Enter 0 to end your session");
        System.out.println("\t1. View all books");
        System.out.println("\t2. Search by title");
        System.out.println("\t3. Search by author");
        System.out.println("\t4. View available books for purchase");
        System.out.println("\t5. View new releases");
        System.out.println("\t6. Purchase one or more copies of a book");
        System.out.println("\t7. Add book(s) to inventory");
        System.out.println("Enter your choice: ");
        choice = keyboard.nextInt();
    }
    return choice;
}
public static void printFarewell(){
    System.out.println("\n\nThank you for using the system!");
}
```

}

So far I've tried:
-getting rid of parameter a for getChoice() and moving the while loop to before if(choice==0) and ended it at the else statement

```
    while(!endSession){
if(choice==0){
        endSession = true;
    }
    if(choice==PRINT_INVENTORY){
        booky.printInventory();
    }
    if(choice==SEARCH_TITLE){
        booky.searchByTitle();
    }
    if(choice==SEARCH_AUTHOR){
        booky.searchByAuthor();
    }
    if(choice==AVAILABLE_BOOKS){
        booky.printAvailableBooks();
    }
    if(choice==NEW_RELEASES){
        booky.printNewReleases();
    }
    if(choice==PURCHASE){
        booky.purchase();
    }
    if(choice==ADD_INVENTORY){
        booky.addToInventory();
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Please choose an option that's actually listed.");
    }
}
```

which resulted in the action looping infinitely (for example: repeatly doing printInventory() until I forced the console to stop).

-moving the boolean endSession to inside getChoice() (no parameters), which almost works, except for the part where it skips doing the action (for example: entering 1, and the menu immediately popping back up without doing printInventory()).

Answer (score 1):

Put the while loop in the main method. Your boolean value never changes inside your method, so your while loop will either run 0 times or infinite times.

Let your helper method collect a single input, and let the loop in your main method inspect the last returned value and determine whether to execute another iteration of the loop.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  int choice = getChoice(); 
  while(choice != 0) {
    choice = getChoice();
  }
}

public static int getChoice() {
  // display menu
  // collect user input
  // return user input
}
```

Comment: To further extend on this, your helper method, ie the method your using for menuing, should do just that: menuing. It should take an input and then execute the correct code. The loop should be external to this, since a menus implementation isn't to also "do x if user exits". The only thing you're code should do is menu and error handling, which in this case is an "else" statement, which is what you have correctly done. Just wanted to share some more info in case you needed a heads up.

Comment: Furthermore, you may find further interest in [switch statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) to clean up the readability of your if statements

Answer (score -1):

1) get rid of the parameters,
2) put the while loop before int choice = getChoice(),
3) end it after the else loop.

I have no idea why that works but I'm too tired to care so yeet!

Comment: There is no such thing as an "else loop".